The invasion of unpleasant thoughts while performing Salah and the possible solutions to get rid of it
Assalamualaikum. For the past few years, I have been finding myself miserably drowning into intrusive,unpleasant and incongruous thoughts while performing Salah or any other forms of Ibadah. Also I feel my mind diverts too easily towards even the tiniest of interferences by side talks even when I am genuinely trying to invest my attention into it. Would anyone please suggest me the most effective "Dua" to help me get rid of this spasmodic mind stirring thoughts that's been pervading my mental space for a while??

Questions asking for personal advice are off-topic.

Not an expert just a fellow muslim.
Hello, All Praise be to Allah
Just know this is verrryyyy common, me personally I have these thoughts all the time. It is really just the Shaytan trying to as I describe it to myself 'frustrate you in your religion' by making things like salah difficult to properly do and even painful.
Here's a video I recommend for you:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XacCbbxc6Fs
It talks more about doubts in procedure rather than doubts in salah however the same explanation applies.
But what I would say
Just IDENTIFY. Just acknowledge the fact that this is the work of a being who does not want you to succeed in prayer, as soon as you can identify this the faster you can help yourself.
Then search for more videos and advice from experts like this Sheik above.
You are not alone, and inshallah that Allah swt will reward you for your perseverance and grant you ease after difficulty, do not despair of Allah's swt mercy, I promise to you as someone who has doubts all the time that even in ones darkest hour to be a muslim it is to be on the straight path.
And Allah swt knows best.

Assalamualaikum brother.Thank you so much. May Allah(swt)bless us both.
